# Conditional-expectation operator inside of expectation operator

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $b(\theta)$ be a parametric function, let $U$ be a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, let $T$ be an unbiased estimator for $b(\theta)$, and denote $g(U)$ as $g(u)=E[T|U=u]$. I am told that the following is true:

$$E[E[(T-g(U))(g(U)-b(\theta))|U]]=E[(g(U)-b(\theta))E[T-g(U)|U]].$$

Can someone explain to me why this equality holds? Is there an extra step that could be written which would make it clearer?

Comment: Note that $g(U)-b(\theta)$ is independent of $T$, since $T$ has been integrated out when taking the expectation $E[T|U=u]$.  Therefore it can be moved outside an expectation-with-respect-to-$T$ operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(One thing that might help a little bit if you start by using bracketing of different sizes to make it clearer to see where terms start and end.  I will do this throughout my working.)  Now, since $b(\theta)$ is a constant, and $g(U)$ is a constant when conditioning on $U$, we therefore have:

$$\mathbb{E} \Big[ \big( (g(U)-b(\theta) \big) \cdot f(T,U) \Big| U \Big] 
= \big( g(U)-b(\theta) \big) \cdot \mathbb{E} \Big[ f(T,U) \Big| U \Big].$$

Substituting $f(T,U) = T-g(U)$ then gives:

$$\mathbb{E} \Big[ (T-g(U))(g(U)-b(\theta)) \Big| U \Big] 
= (g(U)-b(\theta)) \cdot \mathbb{E} \Big[ T-g(U) \Big| U \Big].$$

Both sides of this expression are random variables that are functions of $U$.  Taking expectations of both sides now gives you the formula in your question:

$$\mathbb{E} \Bigg[ \mathbb{E} \Big[ (T-g(U))(g(U)-b(\theta)) \Big| U \Big] \Bigg]
= \mathbb{E} \Bigg[ (g(U)-b(\theta)) \mathbb{E} \Big[ T-g(U) \Big| U \Big] \Bigg].$$

Comment: How did you make the big brackets?

Comment: You use ```\Bigg[``` and ```\Bigg]```.